# Can I use my prepaid phone balance (in pesos) to buy from the Software Centre?

Tags: software-center

Using local network broadband, we can use it to buy games and applications from load balance. Is there any possible ways to use it also in Ubuntu software Center?

additional:
 I'm using mobile broadband for the internet connection,this broadband has a sim card and account number where you can download money from buying a prepaid card worth 100 pesos,300 pesos or 500 pesos, provided by our local network. We use this mobile broadband when there is no wifi connection. There are two kinds of mobile broadband, one is postpaid account and the other is prepaid account. I use prepaid account, this kind of account can load a money for transaction like data plans, from 10 pesos for 30 minutes internet connection or 200 pesos for 5 days internet connection., and this prepaid account can load 5 pesos up to thousands of pesos. 
 Now, if this prepaid mobile broadband can provide money in pesos and has internet connection, I think it can also use it for buying goods or applications or games via internet.

i think its only need a software that can detect the sim card number and the money balance for transactions.

Sorry for my bad english but I hope you got my point.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for currency convertors?

Comment: Do you want to buy games through Ubuntu software center

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to convert currencies? Or do you want to buy applications? Why is broadband relevant?

Comment: You question is *extremely* unclear. Please either clarify and simplify it, or delete your question. Thank you!

Comment: I guess he wants a Ubuntu based software for integrating his mobile with PC , and connect to internet as Mobile modem , and use his Sim card credentials in Dollars to buy stuff.

Comment: Please be aware that adding personal contact and accounts information to a question is never a good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No

The money you load in your prepaid mobile phone account can usually only be used for services provided by the phone company, such as data plans, ringtones, phone games, etc. It **cannot** be used to make purchases over the Internet -- you typically need a credit/debit card or a bank account for that.

#### It cannot be used to make purchases from the Ubuntu Software Centre

While some local phone companies **may** provide a service allowing you to shop at local Internet sellers with the pesos in your prepaid phone account, this does not apply to all sellers on the Internet and definitely not to sellers based in the US (dollars); unfortunately this includes the Ubuntu Software Centre.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to convert currencies from the command line, add the following to the bottom of the `~/.bashrc` file:

```
currency-convert() {
        wget -qO- "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$1&from=$2&to=$3&hl=es" | sed '/res/!d;s/<[^>]*>//g';
}
```

Now, open a new Terminal session. You may now use the `currency-convert` function.

```
currency-convert 15 mxn usd
```

The above converts 15 Mexican pesos to US dollars.

---

Here is a list of short codes you may use for the different pesos of the world:

```
- ARS - Argentine Peso
- CLP - Chilean Peso
- COP - Colombian Peso
- DOP - Dominican Peso
- MXN - Mexican Peso
- PHP - Philippine Peso
- UYU - Uruguayan Peso
```

---

Here is the full list of short codes you may use for conversions.

```
- AED - United Arab Emirates Dirham
- ANG - Netherlands Antillean Guilder
- ARS - Argentine Peso
- AUD - Australian Dollar
- BDT - Bangladeshi Taka
- BGN - Bulgarian Lev
- BHD - Bahraini Dinar
- BND - Brunei Dollar
- BOB - Bolivian Boliviano
- BRL - Brazilian Real
- BWP - Botswanan Pula
- CAD - Canadian Dollar
- CHF - Swiss Franc
- CLP - Chilean Peso
- CNY - Chinese Yuan
- COP - Colombian Peso
- CRC - Costa Rican Colón
- CZK - Czech Republic Koruna
- DKK - Danish Krone
- DOP - Dominican Peso
- DZD - Algerian Dinar
- EEK - Estonian Kroon
- EGP - Egyptian Pound
- EUR - Euro
- FJD - Fijian Dollar
- GBP - British Pound Sterling
- HKD - Hong Kong Dollar
- HNL - Honduran Lempira
- HRK - Croatian Kuna
- HUF - Hungarian Forint
- IDR - Indonesian Rupiah
- ILS - Israeli New Sheqel
- INR - Indian Rupee
- JMD - Jamaican Dollar
- JOD - Jordanian Dinar
- JPY - Japanese Yen
- KES - Kenyan Shilling
- KRW - South Korean Won
- KWD - Kuwaiti Dinar
- KYD - Cayman Islands Dollar
- KZT - Kazakhstani Tenge
- LBP - Lebanese Pound
- LKR - Sri Lankan Rupee
- LTL - Lithuanian Litas
- LVL - Latvian Lats
- MAD - Moroccan Dirham
- MDL - Moldovan Leu
- MKD - Macedonian Denar
- MUR - Mauritian Rupee
- MVR - Maldivian Rufiyaa
- MXN - Mexican Peso
- MYR - Malaysian Ringgit
- NAD - Namibian Dollar
- NGN - Nigerian Naira
- NIO - Nicaraguan Córdoba
- NOK - Norwegian Krone
- NPR - Nepalese Rupee
- NZD - New Zealand Dollar
- OMR - Omani Rial
- PEN - Peruvian Nuevo Sol
- PGK - Papua New Guinean Kina
- PHP - Philippine Peso
- PKR - Pakistani Rupee
- PLN - Polish Zloty
- PYG - Paraguayan Guarani
- QAR - Qatari Rial
- RON - Romanian Leu
- RSD - Serbian Dinar
- RUB - Russian Ruble
- SAR - Saudi Riyal
- SCR - Seychellois Rupee
- SEK - Swedish Krona
- SGD - Singapore Dollar
- SKK - Slovak Koruna
- SLL - Sierra Leonean Leone
- SVC - Salvadoran Colón
- THB - Thai Baht
- TND - Tunisian Dinar
- TRY - Turkish Lira
- TTD - Trinidad and Tobago Dollar
- TWD - New Taiwan Dollar
- TZS - Tanzanian Shilling
- UAH - Ukrainian Hryvnia
- UGX - Ugandan Shilling
- USD - US Dollar
- UYU - Uruguayan Peso
- UZS - Uzbekistan Som
- VEF - Venezuelan Bolívar
- VND - Vietnamese Dong
- XOF - CFA Franc BCEAO
- YER - Yemeni Rial
- ZAR - South African Rand
- ZMK - Zambian Kwacha
```

Comment: Could you put the list of currency codes in a code block so it gets scrollbars? It's kind of disrupting page display.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS done, but... you couldnt do that yourself and then have someone else come along and approve your edit?  You can still propose edits, and have someone with enough rep approve the edit.

Comment: @LordofTime I am required to add 6 non-whitespace characters by some behavior